# Send user input through a windows form

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, forms, mouseevent

I am looking for a way to pass mouse events through a winform without using `Form.TransparencyKey`.
If there is no simple way to do this, is there a way to send a mouse event to a given window handle using Win32 API?

**Edit**
By pass through the winform I do not mean to a parent window, I mean to other applications that reside behind mine.

Comment: So you want to the "transparent" part to be visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is actually much easier than I thought it would be.
This SO answer got me where I needed to be:
[Transparent Window (or Draw to screen) No Mouse Capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318327/transparent-window-or-draw-to-screen-no-mouse-capture)
Also found what looks like a c++ implementation if you want some working code:
[Transparent Window (or Draw to screen) No Mouse Capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318327/transparent-window-or-draw-to-screen-no-mouse-capture)

Answer (score 2):

This may sound overkill, as I saw SLaks's answer..

You would need

1. The handle of the Window using `Handle` property
2. Use pinvoke on the `SendMessage` Win32API
3. One of the parameters to `SendMessage` is WM_LBUTTONDOWN

Here's a declaration for the `SendMessage`

```
[DllImport("user32")] static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

Here's the constants used:

```
public const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;
public const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x202;
```

Typical Invocation:

```
SendMessage(someWindow.Handle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
SendMessage(someWindow.Handle, WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```

The invocation is an example of how to send a mouse left-click to a specified window.

I used [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net) to obtain the correct API.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.