# c#: draw mouse circle outside winform

Tags: c#, mouse

My project is about to control the mouse with the new MS Kinect in C# + Kinect SDK. I decided to use a WinForm Project in VS2010.
So far, I can move the mouse with my hand and can do some mouseclicks inside and outside  my Form. ( So I can control my whole PC with my hands :) )
To control my mouse cursor from a distance, I need to "highlight" it with f.e. a red circle.
So I coded some lines and I can draw a red circle around my mouse cursor and it works fine inside that form. But I want to see the same circle on my desktop too.

Here is an Image to show you my problem.

[image: Mouse Problem]

The Image shows you, that the second circle is beeing cut, when I leave my mouse outside my Form Window, but it shouldn't !

Any ideas ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something that appears to be a solution to your problem. I haven't tested it, but I will shortly.

[Draw directly to screen](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/263740-draw-directly-screen)

**EDIT**

I have been unable to get the solution to work, if someone else can I'd be happy to see what you've done.

Answer (score 3):

Make a new borderless, transparent, topmost window. Then draw your circle within the window, and periodically pole for the mouse coordinates and recenter the window.

Comment: But wouldn't that borderless window intercept his mouse clicks and prevent the interaction with the desktop?

Comment: You can set the window to ignore clicks and pass them through to the window underneath. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318327/transparent-window-or-draw-to-screen-no-mouse-capture/318433#318433

Comment: @JoeWhite Thanks for that, I don't see any issues with this solution.

Comment: @ach: I heard something about it, but thought there would be another way. But for now I layered a second Form above (TopMost = true;) and it works fine. Not perfectly, but acceptable.